# wpf button with hover color and press color ,how to set their default value to background

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a custom wpf button with press color and hover color, but i do not want to set them all the time ,how can make press color and hover color default color as button's background?
`

```
 public Brush HoverBackground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(HoverBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HoverBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HoverBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HoverBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(CustomButton));
```

and some custom propertys

useage:
I do not want to write this all the time

```
<xx:CustomButton Background="xxx",HoverBacground="xx"/>
```

I just want this:`<xx:CustomButton Background="xx"/>`

then the Hoverbackground will be the same as Bacground

`

Answer (score 0):

You can set defaults in the metadata for the DP.

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty HoverBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HoverBackground", 
                                     typeof(Brush),
                                     typeof(CustomButton),
                                     new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Blue));
```

Comment: that is not working...i can not set like this new UIPropertyMetadata(Background)

Answer (score 0):

Set `PropertyMetadata` of `BackgroundProperty` while registering it and set `PropertyChangedCallback` in the metadata.

In `PropertyChangedCallback` of your `BackgroundProperty`, you can set `HoverBckgroundProperty` value.

Comment: i have try this method but it would cause set HoverBackground not working. MSDN document said that set a local value to a property would eliminate the binding